# Replace application from computer with cpu SPARC 64b to computer with cpu Intel 64b

Tags: compiling, solaris, intel, sparc

I have application compiled on server with Solaris 8 and CPU UltraSPARC-III+ x64b
and need replace it (due to server end of life) to another new machine with CPU INTEL 64b , its may be same OS or better to new version of Solaris or best variant to RedHat 6(7), I don't have a source.

Our application is a network application compiled to SunOS 5.8 on sever with CPU UltraSPARC-III+ x64b but this server can down every second. My idea is open new VM 
with SunOS 5.8 and replace application to this new server. But I need help how best way to do it (the way  I understand it is that I can open new server with CentOS 7, and on this server run QEMU with simulation of this architecture and OS), or whether there are other solution to this problem.

Upd: I need install SunOS 5.8 with emulation of CPU - UltraSPARC-III+ x64b on server with CPU - Intel 64bit (Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4) to production application (that need to run nonstop) , and question if/what solution for this problem ?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying tour question.  Before the edit, your question was unclear, but now it's too broad: *You're asking for consultancy,* for which this Q&A site does not lend itself well as we expect very specific questions to which very specific answers can be posted...

Answer (score 4):

You can't run directly Sparc software on X86 CPU. You can try to run it in emulator (like [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) for example). But there is always some trade-off in sense of processor speed.

In some cases you will need to install entire OS (Solaris) to have full ABI.

My personal advise is if this is business critical software maybe will be wise to buy new Sparc machine.

Comment: But a modern Intel CPU is much faster than the 600Mhz to 900Mhz SPARC CPU being replaced, so while emulation won't be as fast as a new SPARC, it may be as fast as a 15 year old SPARC.

Comment: @alanc, right, but you should emulate totally different processor, instructions and so on. Also you will need translation of system calls, libraries... In generally this is quite complex job. If you reach performance of 100Mhz Sparc you should count self lucky :)

Comment: Yes with a plain emulator, but you can do things like recompiling stretches of code on the fly (a bit like the JIT compiler in Java machines).

Comment: @xenoid, that's possible. But if program rely on any specific Solaris library (or ABI interface) this may not work very well. If this is business critical software maybe will be wise to buy new sparc machine :)

Comment: Is qemu up to the task? Last time I've tried, qemu-sparc wasn't able to run solaris. If things have improved, it would be nice to add some links about it (ie about how to run a fully fledged solaris on qemu-sparc, not halfway throught the boot or single user mode and crashing at the 1st `ls` ;-))

Comment: @mosvy apparently it is now, at least for Solaris 9; see [this blog post](https://astr0baby.wordpress.com/2019/02/23/running-solaris-2-9-sparc-on-qemu-system-sparc-in-linux-x86_64-mint-19/) for details.